# How to reference the function with udf type parameters from another pallet in benchmarking

Tags: pallet, benchmarking

Pallet token:

```
  #[pallet::config]
   pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_balances::Config {

       type TokenId: Member
           + Parameter
           + AtLeast32BitUnsigned
           + Default
           + PartialEq
           + Copy
           + Codec
           + MaybeSerializeDeserialize;
   }
```

This is function with the type parameters

```
        pub fn do_mint(
            token: T::TokenId,
            beneficiary: &T::AccountId,
            amount: BalanceOf<T>,
            _maybe_check_issuer: Option<T::AccountId>,
        ) -> DispatchResult
```

The benchmarking code.

```
        where         
        T: pallet_token::Config,
        let token : T::TokenId = 1;
        pallet_token::Pallet::<T>::mint_into(
            token,
            &ferdie,
            10000000.into(),
        )?;
```

result:

```
  --> pallet-verifier/src/benchmarking.rs:87:15
   |
87 |             1.into(),
   |               ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<i32>` is not implemented for `<T as pallet_fuso_token::Config>::TokenId`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<<T as pallet_fuso_token::Config>::TokenId>` for `i32`
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
let token: T::TokenId = 1u32;
```

Comment: --> pallet-fuso-verifier/src/benchmarking.rs:86:34
   |
86 |         let token : T::TokenId = 1u32;
   |                     ----------   ^^^^ expected associated type, found `u32`
   |                     |
   |                     expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as pallet_fuso_token::Config>::TokenId`
                         found type `u32`

Answer (score 5):

The error message is very clear

> the trait `std::convert::From<i32>` is not implemented for `<T as pallet_fuso_token::Config>::TokenId`

i.e. It doesn't know how to convert `i32` to `TokenId`

Your `TokenId` is `AtLeast32BitUnsigned` which implements `From<u32>` so the solution is simple, make it `u32` instead of `i32`.

`1u32.into()`